# Interchangeability between ellipsoidal CRS, and spherical CRS with the authalic radius of the same ellipsoid?

Tags: coordinate-system, spherical-geometry, ellipsoid

The [Uber H3](https://h3geo.org/docs/core-library/overview/) documentation states:

> The coordinate reference system (CRS) is spherical coordinates with the WGS84/EPSG:4326 authalic radius. It is common to use WGS84 CRS data with the H3 library.

To me (a beginner with GIS), this implies that it is considered safe and acceptable to use WGS84 `lon,lat` coordinates as input to H3 functions that assume a *spherical* CRS.

Is this a generally-accepted practice? How much error should I expect in my calculations (e.g. great-circle distance) if I treat them as equivalent?

---

Context:

I am currently working with AIS shipping vessel data, which involves "tracks" or paths of coordinates that sometimes cross oceans (e.g. between South Africa and The Netherlands, or California and Taiwan) and other times lie closer together (e.g. Australia to Malaysia). This work does not require high geographic precision.

However, in the future I might need to work with somewhat higher-precision data, possibly on the order of tens of meters.

I want to understand the implications of any decision I make regarding coordinate reference systems, since other people will be relying on my work in the near future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically for the distance between points, H3 calculates the distance with the [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).
Wikipedia states that this distance: *"[...] cannot be guaranteed correct to better than 0.5%."*.

To know the ellipsoidal distance between two points, we can take advantage of the great work done in the [GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/) library.

For example, between South Africa and The Netherlands (geocoded with Nominatim), the H3 great circle distance is 9208637.41 m, while the WGS84 ellipsoidal distance is 9175894.69 m. The difference is 32742.72 m, i.e., a 0.356 % with respect to the ellipsoidal distance.

Between California and Taiwan:
H3 distance = 10814737.41 m
ellipsoidal distance = 10833905.73 m
Difference in meters = -19168.32 m
Difference in percentage = -0.177 %

Between Australia and Malasya:
H3 distance = 4793739.96 m
ellipsoidal distance = 4785801.50 m
Difference in meters = 7938.46 m
Difference in percentage = 0.166 %

---

From the origin of coordinates, the differences in meters and percentages with respect to the ellipsoidal distance can be represented by the following figures:

[image: 1]

Basic statistics shows: Min = -22212.85 m, Max = 18933.18 m, Mean = -513.63 m.

[image: 2]

Min = -0.112 %, Max = 0.561 %, Mean = 0.025 %.

Since the authalic radius is less than the semi-major axis, and greater than the semi-minor axis, the differences are generally negative in the East-West direction, and positive in the North-South direction.

---

But also the differences depend on the source point from which the distances are measured. To get a rough idea of how the variations can be, we can represent the differences from California:

[image: 3]

Min = -25395.36 m, Max = 36573.36 m, Mean = 1451.22 m.

[image: 4]

Min = -0.261 %, Max = 0.466 %, Mean = -0.007 %.

---

The code used to perform these calculations is at [this notebook](https://github.com/gabriel-de-luca/h3_vs_ellipsoidal_distances/blob/main/h3_vs_ellipsoidal_distances.ipynb).

Comment: That's more thorough than I was expecting, thank you so much! I also was not aware of `geographiclib` before now. < 1 % error is basically irrelevant for my current task, but I greatly appreciate having a clear demonstration and some numbers to refer back to.